# How do I view my saved Wi-Fi logins on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

When I originally connected to my school wifi network I had to enter a username and password (after the wifi password). I now have a new laptop that I am trying to connect but I can't remember the username and password that is needed. There is no one I can ask about it for the next few weeks. Is there any way to view this saved login? Obviously I have admin privileges. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the old laptop is currently connected to that network do the [**following**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023501/windows-find-wireless-network-password):

1. Press the **Start button**, then select **Settings** > **Network & Internet** > **Status** > **Network and Sharing Center**.
2. In **Network and Sharing Center**, next to Connections, select your Wi-Fi network name.
3. In the **Wi-Fi Status** window, select **Wireless Properties**.
4. In **Wireless Network Properties**, select the **Security** tab, then select
   the **Show characters** check box.
5. *Your Wi-Fi network password is displayed in the Network security key
   box.*

---

If that network is not currently connected on the old laptop you can get the password through CMD or Powershell:

1. Right-click on the **Windows icon** on the start screen, and open **Command prompt**/**Powershell as an administrator**. Now type the following command: `netsh wlan show profile`
2. *This command will list all Wi-Fi profiles that you’ve ever connected
   to.*
3. Now for revealing the password of a specific network, use the
   command `netsh wlan show profile “NETWORK NAME” key=clear”`. Substitute “NETWORK NAME” with the Wi-Fi network you want to see the password of
4. *You’ll be able to see Wi-Fi password in ‘**key content**,’ under
   **security settings**.*

Answer (score 2):

A powershell script to get saved Wi-Fi passwords:

```
$profiles=(netsh wlan show profiles | Select-String "All User Profile\s+:\s+(.*)").Matches.Groups | Where-Object {$_.Value -notmatch "All User Profile*"} | Foreach {
  $wlan=netsh wlan show profiles name=$_ key=clear
  [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    'SSID' = ($wlan | Select-String "SSID Name\s+:\s+(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
    'Radio Type' = ($wlan | Select-String "Radio Type\s+:\s+(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
    'Authentication' = ($wlan | Select-String "Authentication\s+:\s+(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
    'Password' = ($wlan | Select-String "Key Content\s+:\s+(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
  }
} | Out-GridView -Title "Saved Wi-Fi passwords (Hold CTRL and select Wi-Fi profiles to apply actions on them)" -Passthru
"You have selected:`n$($profiles)"
$msg=@"
`n
[1] Delete
[2] Quit
"@
choice /c 12 /n /m $Msg
switch($LastExitCode){
1{$profiles|foreach{netsh wlan delete profile name=$_.ssid}}
2{exit 0}
}
```